# Looping and appending in R

Tags: r, loops, append

I have the following R script

```
    optioncost =c(5,52,23,15,134,996,2033,18)
    options=c(0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1)
    cip=c()
    for (options_ind in options)
    {
      if(options_ind==1)
      {
        cip=append(cip,optioncost[which(options==options_ind)])
      }
    }
    cip
```

I am trying to get (52   23   15  134 2033   18). Where as when I run the above script I get an output list which is 6 times the length of expected results. My output from the code is as follows for cip "  52   23   15  134 2033   18   52   23   15  134 2033   18   52   23   15   134 2033   18   52   23   15  134 2033   18   52   23   15  134 2033   18   52   23   15  134 2033   18".

Please help me find out where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`optioncost[which(options==options_ind)]` selects the information you want on its own.

The for loop is superfluous and in this case just repeats the process for as many "1"'s as there are in options, which is 6. Which is why your output data is 6 times larger than he data that you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
optioncost[as.logical(options)]
```

If you want to work with a `for` loop then this the way to go

```
cip=c()
for (i in seq_along(options))
{
  if(options[i]==1)
  {
    cip=append(cip,optioncost[i])
  }
}
cip
```